# Ignore entries in glossary

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am using the `glossaries` package and have a long list of acronyms that are used frequently in the text. Now, I decided that some of the acronyms are not as useful as I thought in the beginning. So, what I would like to have is the following:

I would like to change the definition

```
\newacronym{key}{SA}{some acronym}
```

in a way that all calls to `\ac{key}` (and similar calls for the plural version, `\acs` and so on) are always expanded to `some acronym`. Additionally, the entry should not appear in the list of acronyms. So, it should look like the acronym has never been defined.

Is there any simple way to do this or do I have to replace all calls that use `key` by hand?

Edit: Thanks to cfr who pointed out that I should supply an example. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[shortcuts,smaller]{glossaries}

\newacronym{SA}{SA}{some acronym}
\newacronym{SOA}{SOA}{some other acronym}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

Here, I use \ac{SA}, \ac{SOA}, and of course the plural forms: \acp{SA}, \acp{SOA}. 
Maybe also something like \acs{SA} or \aclp{SA}?

\end{document}
```

This prints

```
Here, I use some acronym (SA), some other acronym (SOA), and of course the plural forms: SAs, SOAs. Maybe also something like SA or some acronyms?
```

What would be the simplest way to obtain without changing anything after `\begin{document}`?

```
Here, I use some acronym, some other acronym (SOA), and of course the plural forms: some acronyms, SOAs. Maybe also something like some acronym or some acronyms?
```

This means, I want to get rid of the acronym "SA" by just changing its definition. I already tried something like

```
\newacronym[text={some acronym},plural={some acronyms},first={some acronym},firstplural={some acronyms}]{SA}{SA}{some acronym}
```

However, this keeps the entry in the Glossary. Additionally, "some acronym" is typeset smaller because of the "smaller" option on first occurence.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is pretty difficult to help without an example to play with, and people will be much more inclined to help if they don't have to construct one from scratch. Something we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue is what's needed here.

Answer (score 4):

This is a way.

Define a new (fake) glossary

```
\newglossary[flg]{fake}{fls}{flo}{Fake Entries}
```

Then, associate each entry you don't want to be printed in the main glossary to this type, for example your entry `SA`, through `type=fake`:

```
\newacronym[type=fake,%
            text={\normalsize some acronym},%
            plural={\normalsize some acronyms},%
            first={\normalsize some acronym},%
            firstplural={\normalsize some acronyms}]{SA}{SA}{some acronym}
```

Finally, just print the main glossary, that is substitute

```
\printglossaries
```

with

```
\printglossary[type=main]
```

Note that I've added `\normalsize` inside the definition of `SA` to avoid having the entries printed in `smaller` size.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[shortcuts,smaller]{glossaries}

\newglossary[flg]{fake}{fls}{flo}{Fake Entries}

\newacronym[type=fake,%
            text={\normalsize some acronym},%
            plural={\normalsize some acronyms},%
            first={\normalsize some acronym},%
            firstplural={\normalsize some acronyms}]{SA}{SA}{some acronym}

\newacronym{SOA}{SOA}{some other acronym}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=main]

Here, I use \ac{SA}, \ac{SOA}, and of course the plural forms: \acp{SA}, \acp{SOA}.
Maybe also something like \acs{SA} or \aclp{SA}?

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I have a couple of issues with this method. The `first` field doesn't have an effect (you can see this in the example you give, there shouldn't be an "(SA)"). Also, \glsresetall doesn't seem to reset it.